# Почему в данном фрагменте кода происходит memory leak?

Tags: c#, потоки-данных

Почему в данном фрагменте кода происходи memory leak?

Насколько я понимаю, то берётся копия потока, над ней выполняются операции, а затем в памяти "оригинальный поток" заменяется копией?

```
protected virtual Stream RenderXhtml(Stream inputDocumentStream, IFormatType styleSheetInfo)
    {
        var docReader = XmlReader.Create(inputDocumentStream);

        var xhtmlStream = styleSheetInfo.TransformXmlDoc(docReader, this.BuildTransformParam());

        inputDocumentStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        xhtmlStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    
        CreateFileDump(xhtmlStream, ".html");

        xhtmlStream = TableConverter.ConvertTablesToImages(xhtmlStream, publicationName);

        return xhtmlStream;
    }
```

Comment: Никаких здесь утечек нет и быть не может, так как в принципе в данном методе нет работы с неуправляемой памятью. Вы что-то перепутали. Что касается `IDisposable`, то в данном случае ответственность за них лежит на вызывающем коде, а не на этом методе. Единственная странность, почему используется поле, а не локальная переменная, ну либо вы криво скопировали код.

Comment: Что касается рассуждений о копиях, то то в показанном коде об этом ничего нет, так что это рассуждения о сферичесеих потоках в вакууме, и непонятно, какие комментарии вы бы хотели получить к этим рассуждениям.

Comment: @aepot подправил на полный код.
При возврате результата функцией ConvertTableToImages не будет утечки так как я старый стрим не закрываю, но создаёшь новый?

Comment: Ответ тот же. Ну задиспозить здесь лишнее теперь можно.

Comment: @aepot а что тут лишнее?

Comment: `using var docReader = ...`, `using var xhtmlStream = ...`. Кстати, обе строки с `Seek` можно удалить, толку от них никакого. Только что созданный стрим всегда чистается сначала. `xhtmlStream = TableConverter...` надо положить в другую переменную, или написать проще `return TableConverter.ConvertTablesToImages(xhtmlStream, publicationName);`

Comment: @aepot Вопрос возник из-за замечания тех. лида к моему коду в фрагменте xhtmlStream = TableConverter.ConvertTablesToImages(xhtmlStream, publicationName); . Будто там memory leak... А в моём понимании я затираю старый стрим новым ( созданным в функции )?     Что касается Seek() для inputDocumentStream - стрим же не новосозданной, получается для него seek() необходим?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь пару потоков лишних задиспозить не мешало бы.

[Использование объектов, реализующих IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects)

```
protected virtual Stream RenderXhtml(Stream inputDocumentStream, IFormatType styleSheetInfo)
{
    inputDocumentStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    using var docReader = XmlReader.Create(inputDocumentStream);
    using var xhtmlStream = styleSheetInfo.TransformXmlDoc(docReader, this.BuildTransformParam());

    CreateFileDump(xhtmlStream, ".html");
    xhtmlStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return TableConverter.ConvertTablesToImages(xhtmlStream, publicationName);
}
```

Но вообще точное решение очень сильно зависит от поведения вызываемых методов. Например неизвестно, у `ConvertTablesToImages` жадное поведение или ленивое. Во втором случае диспозить созданные потоки нельзя, их должен закрывать сам метод `ConvertTablesToImages` по окончании использования, либо у него должен был аргумент, отвечающий за управление таким поведением.